# How to set a background image for each list item in the navigation drawer.

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to replace every list item in the android navigation drawer with different images. Can anyone elaborate on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: overide getVIew() method in adaptar class and for specific position change bknd accordingly

Answer (score 0):

first you can create an array like so

```
final String[] NAV_OPTIONS =  new String[]{"menuOne","menuTwo","menuThree","menuFour"};
```

then when we pass the our listview to the adapter we do it the like this

```
leftDraw.setAdapter(new menuAdapter(Nav_OPTIONS));
```

The adapter should look something like this

```
    public class menuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] menu;

        public menuAdapter(String[] data) {

            menu = data;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

            //here we just check the position and depending on the string inflate one of our layout xmls
            if(menu[position].equals("menuOne")){
               //inflate our first layout
               convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.menu_one, null);

            }
            else if(menu[position].equals("menuTwo")){
                //inflate our second layout
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.menu_two, null);
           }
           else if(menu[position].equals("menuThree")){
                //inflate our third
                convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.menu_three. null);
           }
           else if(menu[position].equals("MenuFour")){
               //and finally our fourth
               convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.menu_four, null);

               //within these if statements we can inflate any buttons, switches, imageviews  
               //we just need to reference them from within the statement as we're infalting the xml in which they are contained
               Button example = (button). convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_button);

           }

           //return the view 
           return covertView;
}
```

You basically just need to create seperate XML's and inflate them depending on the position in the array.

**EDIT**

I just realised you may simply be asking to just add a separate image and not an entire layout. In which case my solution may be a bit more than you need.

A different image works in a similar way though. Simply store your your images in an array and retrieve them based on the index (int position) of the adapter.